# What is forever in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, forever

I am having hard time understanding what is **forever** in nodejs.

Can someone explain what is forever in simplest way that i can understand and what is the purpose of it

Comment: `forever` keeps the node server _alive_. When the node server is stopped becaluse of some error, exception, etc. `forever` automatically restarts it. `A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given node script runs continuously (i.e. forever)` Read more https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

Comment: @Tushar you might want to put this as an answer which should be the accepted one

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`forever` is a node.js package that is used to keep the server *alive* even when the server crash/stops. When the node server is stopped because of some error, exception, etc. forever automatically restarts it

From the npmjs https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever

> A simple CLI tool for ensuring that a given node script runs continuously (i.e. forever)

Forever can be used as

```
forever start app.js
```

It provides many useful functions which you can see in the link above.

Directly quoting from http://blog.nodejitsu.com/keep-a-nodejs-server-up-with-forever/

> The purpose of **Forever** is to keep a child process (such as your node.js web server) running continuously and automatically restart it when it exits unexpectedly.

Comment: If you are interested in `running` forever as service https://www.exratione.com/2013/02/nodejs-and-forever-as-a-service-simple-upstart-and-init-scripts-for-ubuntu/

Comment: Forever tagged [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/forever) on SO

Answer (score 4):

Forever basically allows you to run your nodejs application as a process.

Without forever you might type `npm start` or `node index.js` to start your application and it will run in your terminal session.

With forever, you can start it off and still have access to your terminal session/close it.

Comment: NO! `forever` keeps the node server _alive_. When the node server is stopped becaluse of some error, exception, etc. `forever` automatically restarts it.

Answer (score -1):

You can even use the `nohup` command it simply ignores the hang up signal.

```
node index.js && nohup -& (to run as a background process - no hiccup)
```

Comment: you would need to run int in a while loop , inifinitely to make your answer valid